# How to configure ESLint Settings in Azure DevOps YAML?

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, eslint

I'm learning how to use YAML files in my build pipeline and I need to change eslint settings.  Specifically, I'm trying to disable the rule that checks for console statements. I've modified it in my local .eslintrc.js file, but the pipeline doesn't appear to use the settings in that file. Am I going about this the right way?

Here's what I have so far:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: Did you include eslint in your package.json dependencies?

Comment: @Adam No, I don't think so. I see entires for "babel-eslint", "eslint", and "eslint-plugin-vue" under "devDepencies" in package.json.  If I copy those to "dependencies", will the Azure node compiler look for the lint settings in .eslintrc.js?

Comment: With Azure DevOps there technically isn't a difference between dependencies and devDependencies since they all get installed with `npm install`. Can you edit to include your entire package.json file and your root directory structure? If the pipeline isn't recognizing your .eslintrc file, it's either in the wrong place or something isn't pointing to it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not added any command to run the linter.
Add an additional command like so in the yaml.

```
- script: |
    npm install
    eslint src
    npm run build
    displayName: 'npm install, lint and build'
```

Or for better clarity, you can add a custom script in the package.json file, as below

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "linter": "eslint src",
    ...
}
```

then call it from the yaml.

```
- script: |
    npm install
    npm run linter
    npm run build
    displayName: 'npm install, lint and build'
```