# How to add ESLint Settings in Azure DevOps XML?

Tags: xml, azure, azure-devops, eslint

I am trying to add eslint setting to my Azure XML file. I have already existing project and need to add this setting.

Comment: [How to configure ESLint Settings in Azure DevOps YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422288/how-to-configure-eslint-settings-in-azure-devops-yaml) and [ESLint as a task for Azure DevOps](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/14773)

Comment: My questions is more about XML and Azure DevOps. I hadn`t seen the same question on stack overflow. Yeah, YAML question exist, but YAML is slightly different from XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put inside the Exec line command from package.json, which run eslint `<Exec Command="npm run lint" />`